# Inserting a new value in binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, arrays, data-structures, binary-tree, performance

Using an algorithm `Tree-Insert(T, v)` that inserts a new value `v` into a binary search tree `T`, the following algorithm grows a binary search tree by repeatedly inserting each value in a given section of an array into the tree:

> `Tree-Grow(A, first, last, T)
>
>     1 for i ← first to last
>
>     2     do Tree-Insert(T, A[i])`

1. If the tree is initially empty, and the length of array section (i.e., last-first+1) is n, what are the best-case and the worst-case asymptotic running time of the above algorithm, respectively?
2. When n = 7, give a best-case instance (as an array containing digits 1 to 7, in certain order), and a worst-case instance (in the same form) of the algorithm.
3. If the array is sorted and all the values are distinct, find a way to modify Tree-Grow, so that it will always build the shortest tree.
4. What are the best-case and the worst-case asymptotic running time of the modified algorithm, respectively?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: This should be fairly easy explained by a quick look in your algo book. If its the same one I had in college there is a whole section with the above data in it.

Comment: @Russel: If I had to guess, what he has so far is a take-home test, and four user names already today.

Comment: Please stop tagging this `possible-homework`, it is not what tags are for. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34503/should-the-possible-homework-tag-be-discouraged and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: This is a straight-up homework question or an exam question. Wow. IMO it should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Please tag homework questions with the `homework` tag. In order to do well on your final exam, I suggest you actually learn this stuff, but I'm not here to judge you.

1) It takes O(n) to iterate from first to last. It takes O(lg n) to insert into a binary tree, therefore it the algorithm that you have shown takes O(n lg n) in the best case.

The worst case of inserting into a binary tree is when the tree is really long, but not very bushy; similar to a linked list. In that case, it would take O(n) to insert, therefore it would take O(n^2) in the worst case.

2) Best Case: [4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7], Worst Case: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

3) Use the n/2 index as the root, then recursively do this for the left side and right side of the array.

4) O(n lg n) in the best and worst case.

I hope this helps.